# Highlighting the word on click in a sentence

Tags: javascript

In Javascript, I've written a script to highlight a word when a user clicks it.

This question is already answered in some places. I have made use of the answers in those solutions to create this script that works pretty fine.

```
$(".clickable").click(function(e){
      var selectedVocabPhrase = null
      var matchedVocabPhrase = null
      var selection = window.getSelection()

      if (selection.anchorNode.parentNode.nodeName === 'STRONG') {
        selectedVocabPhrase = selection.anchorNode.parentNode.innerText
      }
      if (!selection || selection.rangeCount < 1) return true;
      var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
      var node = selection.anchorNode;

      var word_regexp = /^\w*$/;

      // Extend the range backward until it matches word beginning
      while ((range.startOffset > 0) && range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
        range.setStart(node, (range.startOffset - 1));
      }
      // Restore the valid word match after overshooting
      if (!range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
        range.setStart(node, range.startOffset + 1);
      }

      // Extend the range forward until it matches word ending
      while ((range.endOffset < node.length) && range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
        range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);
      }
      // Restore the valid word match after overshooting
      if (!range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
        range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset - 1);
      }
  console.log(range.toString().trim());
});
```

JSBIN link is here...

https://jsbin.com/faxibolebu/edit?html,js,console,output

However, there are problems/ For example, if a word has hypth - for example co-worker, then if co is clicked only co is ighlighted. if 'worker' is clicked only 'worker' is highlighted. Similar problem hapens with words contain apostrophe, such as couldn't. the word gets split.

I'm unable to solve this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than matching `\w*` - which matches word characters only - consider matching `\S*`, which matches any non-space characters.

In order to exclude trailing `.`s and `,`s, add `(?![.,])\S` to the end (lookahead for anything but a `.` or `,`, then match any non-space character).

In addition, if the user *deliberately* clicks and drags to select text, you might consider leaving the existing highlighting as-is (which is more user-friendly and avoids strangeness and/or ambiguous behavior like when multiple words are selected). Do this by checking if the `startOffset` is equal to the `endOffset`:

```js
$(".clickable").click(function(e) {
  var selectedVocabPhrase = null
  var matchedVocabPhrase = null
  var selection = window.getSelection()

  if (selection.anchorNode.parentNode.nodeName === 'STRONG') {
    selectedVocabPhrase = selection.anchorNode.parentNode.innerText
  }
  if (!selection || selection.rangeCount < 1) return true;
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  if (range.startOffset !== range.endOffset) {
    // User selected at least one character themselves; don't change anything
    return;
  }
  var node = selection.anchorNode;

  var word_regexp = /^(?:|\S*(?![.,])\S)$/;

  // Extend the range backward until it matches word beginning
  while ((range.startOffset > 0) && range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
    range.setStart(node, (range.startOffset - 1));
  }
  // Restore the valid word match after overshooting
  if (!range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
    range.setStart(node, range.startOffset + 1);
  }

  // Extend the range forward until it matches word ending
  while ((range.endOffset < node.length) && range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
    range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset + 1);
  }
  // Restore the valid word match after overshooting
  if (!range.toString().match(word_regexp)) {
    range.setEnd(node, range.endOffset - 1);
  }
  console.log(range.toString().trim());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="clickable">
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="v-popover">
        <span aria-describedby="popover_8k4slo118o" tabindex="-1" class="trigger" style="display: inline-block;">
            <span>When office worker Laura Garzón visited a butcher's shop in Bogota, she <strong>couldn't believe her eyes</strong>.
            </span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="v-popover">
        <span aria-describedby="popover_tb8xft1vhg" tabindex="-1" class="trigger" style="display: inline-block;">
            <span> Standing behind the counter was her co-worker, Jorge Castro.
            </span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="v-popover"><span aria-describedby="popover_1b3s8fw9ee" tabindex="-1" class="trigger" style="display: inline-block;">
          <span style="cursor: pointer; display: inline !important;"> But instead of wearing a suit and tie, he was wearing a bloodstained butcher's apron and white cap.
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would this not also include punctuation in the selection, as in the comma after "co-worker"?

Comment: In that case, what will happen if there is a comma or a full stop after the word. How to avoid that from getting highlighted?

Comment: Maybe this might help: `/^(\w\S\w|\w)*$/`. Takes either a special char that is surrounded by letters, or a single letter. But I can foresee that this would not select apostrophe at the end of a word (e.g. "the parents' children"). Alternatively, you could specify the exact list of accepted characters, if that's feasible.

Comment: You can negative lookahead for `[.,]` to avoid matching dots and commas in the last position. Remember there *can* be words that end in punctuation that can be considered to be part of the word, eg `James'`. Not sure about a whitelist, there are *lots* of characters one would have to account for, I think